# Single lint report in multi-modular Android project

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, lint

Does anyone know if it's possible to have single Gradle task for Lint check in the multi-modular Android project?
The aim is to have the only one HTML/XML report for all modules (app + a few Android libraries).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In order to do that configure android lint only in the module where other modules are used as dependencies and enable `checkDependencies` in `lintOptions`.

ex:

There is an application module called `app` which uses `feature_1`, `feature_2`, `feature_3` library modules as dependencies, so set `checkDependencies` to `true` in `lintOptions` of `app` module `build.gradle` file.

```
android{

    lintOptions{

        checkDependencies true // <---
        xmlReport false
        htmlReport true
        htmlOutput file("${project.rootDir}/build/reports/android-lint.html")

    }
}
```

**Note**:

when you run `./gradlew lint` this will generate reports for every dependency module at each modules `build/reports` directory, **BUT a report with all lint issues related to the project will be generated at the specified location.**

---

Reference: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/lint-dev/TpTMBMlwPPs/WZHCu59TAwAJ

Comment: Note that lint is much slower with the combined report, as indicated in that google groups discussion:

"lint is slower since shared modules are analyzed many many times"

Comment: Thanks for these parameters! I set `xmlReport = false
htmlReport = false` and received all warnings in Terminal. Because I have many modules, I got all warnings in one place, not in many HTML files.

Comment: Do you know how to create combined `lint-baseline` file?

Comment: Hello. I am from 2022. Now this flag does not slow down the lint check and the check runs in parallel! https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?hl=lt#lint-behavior-changes